# Explaining the convergence of $\int_{0}^{1} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx$ using the properties of essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

Because the function $\frac{1}{z}$ has a pole at $z=0$, the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x} $ doesn't converge.

On the other hand, the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx $ converges even though the function $\sin \left(\frac{1}{z} \right)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

Can an essential singularity be a weaker singularity than an pole?

**EDIT**:

Originally I had $\int_{0}^{1} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \, dx$ (which converges despite the fact that $\sin \left(\frac{1}{z^{2}} \right)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essential singularities have the property of being both small and large near the singularity (see the [Picard Theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) or, as Martin comments, the [Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)). In this case, you've chosen a path to the singularity where its size is not big.

If instead, you chose to approach along the line $z=(1+i)t$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$), then
$$
\sin\left(\frac1{z^2}\right)=-i\sinh\left(\frac1{2t^2}\right)
$$
which grows very fast near $z=0$, faster than any power of $\left|\frac1z\right|$.

---

**For the modified question**

Approach along the line $z=it$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$), then
$$
\sin\left(\frac1z\right)=-i\sinh\left(\frac1t\right)
$$
which grows very fast near $z=0$, faster than any power of $\left|\frac1z\right|$.

Comment: Do you mean that the value of $f(z)$ is both small and large near the essential singularity? So it's all about how you approach it?

Comment: Yes. According to the Big Picard Theorem, all values (except possibly one) are attained infinitely often in any neighborhood of an essential singularity.

Comment: And for a pole, the value of $f(z)$ is large in any punctured neighborhood?

Comment: Yes. For some $n$, $f(z)(z-z_0)^n$ is analytic in a neighborhood of a [pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_%28complex_analysis%29) at $z_0$. The least such $n$ is called the order of the pole.

Comment: Instead of Picard's theorems, [Casorati-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati–Weierstrass_theorem) would be enough for the qualitative statement in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Martin: indeed, thanks. Picard is just what came to mind as I was writing. I will include your link.